# SQL Server, variable in IN Clause

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, in-clause

I want to use a variable inside `IN` clause, similar to this:

```
Declare @tt NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @tt = '02ea2b81-07f0-4660-bca1-81563f65bf65','07728975-cb1d-484c-8894-14f5b793cbef','1071ee4f-a214-443f-8694-0b3e9d2dc77e','120d2881-b04f-4707-a925-e4d941f03201','23af54a7-6666-4747-a74a-c2101cda59b0','260d2ce5-f4f0-4a0b-aa0b-3e1d2b5fcfeb','2710a913-13e7-4300-91f1-2646e2f8449e','2cebc482-4917-4aa3-973b-2481619a78e7','2d2269a4-9164-4dae-a732-90448d761509','2d29c707-1c5f-4e00-bd3c-bfd2ec2c6e29','3ead72a1-de91-47e9-8038-cc504a5274ec','40a03f53-7fd7-488d-922d-3435652219cb','43c93954-2e75-4d47-a53f-848eee609cf1','441e1a59-d397-4981-b770-01fb4594152e','4dacc9df-0536-46f6-af5d-78610ed998cd','4e4910ee-db9b-45ba-8872-2819dcefdc2c','4f9fd3ef-ba81-44bb-8c75-7cf6998e115e','60d9c73f-46c3-4ab1-9a4e-5440d18a0fd8','63e0cc57-1803-473f-847d-f3318f70c993','6510de61-9a1d-4f69-bec4-a744ea2bb847','799e2e55-2ba8-4772-8aff-331ed1817225','7be022db-4d37-4964-9005-3de7c6286027','85ba80c3-5c8b-4097-b5c9-c0d55ac6cf2f','8bc45b07-6a65-43c2-a41e-e791b085a053','8ca2d4a7-f4d6-4b56-aa41-42550e3a11b5','8fa7c3f6-e042-4b93-829f-79b8946a909e','ab34d18a-9482-4146-adb2-7e45e32f8cdd','ac43b44b-651c-4a98-a55f-82878cc8c656','ad9f222c-a98e-44eb-af9e-6f083941be9e','af7e8d24-9126-4d9b-a48a-75bf344c3529','b0e95518-0fef-46ba-81f4-0d1356ebc135','b1f1810f-3044-40b3-b218-5bb02d8922bd','b32ebf2b-f247-4032-8a37-285e4c3488a9','b93a8bb7-c62f-47b7-86ba-0421eb67ca14','c5342d7e-1667-47cb-bccf-91c5e8e9f18c','e2cf46f6-a522-4a96-8a84-f1ce3818c364','f01f4010-a192-43ca-a3bf-157379f4779d','f0f168ec-f043-41ef-90d3-3eac68b90334','f99af706-e1bb-42ba-bdf9-348a3b02c25e','fe691dee-b133-4d1c-90a3-8889cd3482d2';
Select * from table where assessmentId IN(@tt)
```

But this query is failing, saying `Incorrect syntax near ','`. The same query will work if I will not use variable in `IN` clause and directly pass the Id's

```
Select * from table where AssessmentId IN
                             ('02ea2b81-07f0-4660-bca1-81563f65bf65','07728975-cb1d-484c-8894-14f5b793cbef','1071ee4f-a214-443f-8694-0b3e9d2dc77e','120d2881-b04f-4707-a925-e4d941f03201','23af54a7-6666-4747-a74a-c2101cda59b0','260d2ce5-f4f0-4a0b-aa0b-3e1d2b5fcfeb','2710a913-13e7-4300-91f1-2646e2f8449e','2cebc482-4917-4aa3-973b-2481619a78e7','2d2269a4-9164-4dae-a732-90448d761509','2d29c707-1c5f-4e00-bd3c-bfd2ec2c6e29','3ead72a1-de91-47e9-8038-cc504a5274ec','40a03f53-7fd7-488d-922d-3435652219cb','43c93954-2e75-4d47-a53f-848eee609cf1','441e1a59-d397-4981-b770-01fb4594152e','4dacc9df-0536-46f6-af5d-78610ed998cd','4e4910ee-db9b-45ba-8872-2819dcefdc2c','4f9fd3ef-ba81-44bb-8c75-7cf6998e115e','60d9c73f-46c3-4ab1-9a4e-5440d18a0fd8','63e0cc57-1803-473f-847d-f3318f70c993','6510de61-9a1d-4f69-bec4-a744ea2bb847','799e2e55-2ba8-4772-8aff-331ed1817225','7be022db-4d37-4964-9005-3de7c6286027','85ba80c3-5c8b-4097-b5c9-c0d55ac6cf2f','8bc45b07-6a65-43c2-a41e-e791b085a053','8ca2d4a7-f4d6-4b56-aa41-42550e3a11b5','8fa7c3f6-e042-4b93-829f-79b8946a909e','ab34d18a-9482-4146-adb2-7e45e32f8cdd','ac43b44b-651c-4a98-a55f-82878cc8c656','ad9f222c-a98e-44eb-af9e-6f083941be9e','af7e8d24-9126-4d9b-a48a-75bf344c3529','b0e95518-0fef-46ba-81f4-0d1356ebc135','b1f1810f-3044-40b3-b218-5bb02d8922bd','b32ebf2b-f247-4032-8a37-285e4c3488a9','b93a8bb7-c62f-47b7-86ba-0421eb67ca14','c5342d7e-1667-47cb-bccf-91c5e8e9f18c','e2cf46f6-a522-4a96-8a84-f1ce3818c364','f01f4010-a192-43ca-a3bf-157379f4779d','f0f168ec-f043-41ef-90d3-3eac68b90334','f99af706-e1bb-42ba-bdf9-348a3b02c25e','fe691dee-b133-4d1c-90a3-8889cd3482d2');
```

How can I use variable in `IN` clause using the first approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to insert the values into a temp table.

Something like

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(
        assessmentId VARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO @TempTable 
VALUES 
('02ea2b81-07f0-4660-bca1-81563f65bf65'),
('07728975-cb1d-484c-8894-14f5b793cbef'),
('1071ee4f-a214-443f-8694-0b3e9d2dc77e'),
('120d2881-b04f-4707-a925-e4d941f03201'),
('23af54a7-6666-4747-a74a-c2101cda59b0'),
('260d2ce5-f4f0-4a0b-aa0b-3e1d2b5fcfeb'),
('2710a913-13e7-4300-91f1-2646e2f8449e'),
('2cebc482-4917-4aa3-973b-2481619a78e7')

SELECT  *
FROM    table 
where   AssessmentId IN (SELECT assessmentId FROM @TempTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to specify *multiple* values, use a data type that supports *multiple* values (as opposed to a scalar variable). Here we're using a table variable:

```
Declare @tt table (value nvarchar(50) not null)
insert into @tt (value) values
('02ea2b81-07f0-4660-bca1-81563f65bf65'),('07728975-cb1d-484c-8894-14f5b793cbef'),('1071ee4f-a214-443f-8694-0b3e9d2dc77e'),
('120d2881-b04f-4707-a925-e4d941f03201'),('23af54a7-6666-4747-a74a-c2101cda59b0'),('260d2ce5-f4f0-4a0b-aa0b-3e1d2b5fcfeb'),
...
Select * from table where assessmentId IN(select value from @tt)
```