# SSRS Multiple Value, Scalar variable type?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'd like to replicate the variables passed into a certain SQL Script contained in an SSRS report for testing on a copy of said script (outside of SSRS).
One of the parameters happens to allow multiple values, and is used in the script like so:

```
SELECT blah, blah2 FROM theTable WHERE blah3 in (@TheParameter)
```

Which works fine, I can specify multiple parameters to be shoved into @TheParameter and the script happily runs in SSRS.

However, I cannot replicate a value of @TheParameter inside the script to emulate this at all (i.e. `Declare @TheParameter VARCHAR(150) = 'Param1,Param2'` doesn't work)

Based on other questions in StackOverflow, it seems SSRS doesn't actually use @TheParameter as a scalar variable at all (which is why I can get away with not DECLARE-ing it in the script inside SSRS) but instead replaces it with the text of the parameter's value list.

I guess my question is, is it possible to keep my `in (@TheParameter)` code pieces or do I need to maintain two separate versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to maintain two seperate versions (unless you can get away with testing with only one value).

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358811/sql-server-variable-in-in-clause)

Comment: Yeah, it was looking like that would be the case. *sigh* for double-standards... ;)